# How to display Math equations in React Native View

Tags: react-native

How to render Math equations in React Native Views? For web applications, we can use LaTex or MathJax solutions. But React Native renders native components. Using WebView will be bad as MathJax loading will take time for each WebView component.
How do we render Math equations on React Native Views (non-WebView)?

Comment: guys till now no solution , me too i want this answer

Comment: Were you able to find an appropriate solution?

Comment: @suman could you find any solution?

Comment: No. I did not find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

MathJax let you use render `SVG` so you may try to generate SVG  and then render it inside of React Native ( I am pretty sure that it won't work out of the box, but at least it is a way )

Answer (score 0):

There is a library for MathJax in React Native. Library does not work properly sometimes, but you should try it. https://github.com/calvinkei/react-native-mathjax#readme

Usage

```
<MathJax
  // HTML content with MathJax support
  html={'$\sum_{i=0}^n i^2 = \frac{(n^2+n)(2n+1)}{6}$<br><p>This is an equation</p>'}
  // MathJax config option
  mathJaxOptions={{
    messageStyle: 'none',
    extensions: [ 'tex2jax.js' ],
    jax: [ 'input/TeX', 'output/HTML-CSS' ],
    tex2jax: {
      inlineMath: [ ['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)'] ],
      displayMath: [ ['$$','$$'], ['\\[','\\]'] ],
      processEscapes: true,
    },
    TeX: {
      extensions: ['AMSmath.js','AMSsymbols.js','noErrors.js','noUndefined.js']
    }
  }}
  {...WebView props}
/>
```

Comment: Please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.